# Can you call a cheeseburger a hamburger?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, food

Can you call a cheeseburger a hamburger? I am eating self-made ones.

Comment: By the way, you want to call them "homemade" instead of "self-made".

Comment: Welcome to the site. This question is too basic; it can be definitively and
permanently answered by a single
link to a standard internet reference
source designed specifically to find
that type of information. Next time please check a [dictionary](http://m.dictionary.com/d/?q=cheeseburger&o=0&l=dir) first:  ***"cheeseburger:  hamburger with melted cheese"***.

Comment: Everybody is saying you can, don't you think it is better if you can? Otherwise it would be neurotic.

Comment: @user128360: Better if you can?  I don't know about that.  I think it tastes the same, no matter what you call it.  "_I like mine with lettuce and tomato_..."

Answer (score 5):

Technically, a cheeseburger is a specific form of hamburger.

But, if someone asks for a hamburger and they get a cheeseburger, they will probably be upset at not getting what they wanted. That is, the term 'hamburger' usually is used for the specific plain version, not for any kind of hamburger, at least with respect to added cheese; a cheeseburger is not a hamburger.

So you can call a cheeseburger a hamburger in a burger construction manual, but not when accepting orders in a restaurant.

Comment: Why is http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65060/mild-red-condiment still closed?

Comment: @AngloSaxon: as interesting as that question is, why are you asking here on my answer to a question about cheeseburger? Is it because both have something to do with food?

Comment: Yes. Reading your answer I understand you are interested in food  questions, so you could add a comment on 'paprika'.

Comment: @AngloSaxon: all these comments are irrelevant here. Please continue at that question.

Answer (score 3):

In America at least, you could refer to both as "**burgers**".

Comment: How about referring to them as sandwiches?

Comment: This would be problematic. Everybody knows they are sandwiches, but they are only "technically" sandwiches and not "really" sandwiches. On a menu board it would be rare to see "burgers" listed under "sandwiches".